# Extract single value from JSON data using key

Tags: python, json, key, extract

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
  "status": {
    "status_code": 0,
    "status_message": "SUCCESS"
  },
  "device_id": 89911454,
  "type": "obs_st",
  "source": "cache",
  "summary": {
    "pressure_trend": "falling",
    "strike_count_1h": 0,
    "strike_count_3h": 0,
    "precip_total_1h": 0.0,
    "precip_accum_local_yesterday": 0.0,
    "precip_accum_local_yesterday_final": 0.0,
    "precip_analysis_type_yesterday": 1,
    "feels_like": 33.3,
    "heat_index": 33.3,
    "wind_chill": 33.3
  },
  "obs": [
    [1600214324, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1012.8, 33.3, 35, 27898, 1.94, 232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.56, 1, 0, null, null, 0]
  ]
}
```

I only want the value for "heat_index".  In this case that "heat_index" = 33.3.  I've not been able to figure out how.  Can anyone give me a hand with this?  Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: Doesn't `myJson['summary']['heat_index']` work?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but whenever I do something like that I get this error message: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Yes, it does work if I do this first: json_data = json.loads(result)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a json object stored in string format then first you need to decode it before you can access it using the "**[ ]**" operators.  Luckily Python as usual already has a library for this.  The [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library has the ability to encode, decode and pretty print json data.

```
import json

file = open("your-json-file-here.json")
jsonString = file.read()
file.close()

jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)
print(jsonObject["summary"]["heat_index"])
```

It doesn't matter too much how you get the json string as long as you call the loads function on it.

Yours Aye,

Omar EQ